# Can Flyway coeexist with unmanaged database objects?

Tags: java, mysql, flyway

Does [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org) have to manage ALL the objects in my database schema?   Or is it permissible to have objects that are dropped/recreated outside of the Flyway system, for example tables containing lookups that are generated and populated separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your unmanaged DB objects are not connected to your managed ones, this is (technically) not a problem.

If they are connected to each other, your are likely to have some problems in certain scenarios:

- Setting up a new database with flyway from scratch won't work because the flyway migration cannot be intercepted with other unmanaged scripts.
- If your unmanaged objects are not compatible at any time, you will break the flyway migration at some point.

In any case, if you start using unmanaged DB scripts, you won't have a reproducible migration path for your database anymore, which is one of the key features of flyway.